# How i can force my div to display in block?

Tags: css, html

I'm new to this forum , so excuse me if I ask a trivial question. I try to develop a website with a theme that uses Bootstrap purchased .

I quickly learned how to use it but there is an alignment problem with some blocks and I can not find where the problem comes .

Here is what is expected (schematic) :

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/38/1442431886-1.png

And this is what i have actually :

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/38/1442431875-sans-titre.png

This is my html code (with some css adds) :

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <!-- First player -->

        <div class="caption">
            <h1 class="text-center">Nolife de la semaine</h1><img alt="..."
            src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/38/1442431132-default-skin.png" style=
            "display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

            <h3 class="text-center">ilies91</h3>

            <h4 class="text-center">34 heures de jeu</h4>
        </div><!-- Second player -->

        <div class="caption text-center">
            <div class="pull-left"><img alt="..." src=
            "http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/38/1442431133-first4ever.png" style=
            "display: block;width: 85px; height: 85px; text-align:center"></div>

            <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:10px;">
                <h5>Hannibal</h5>

                <h6>28 heures de jeu</h6>
            </div>
        </div><!-- Third player  -->

        <div class="caption text-center">
            <div class="pull-left"><img alt="..." src=
            "http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/38/1442431133-luciole.png"></div>

            <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:10px;">
                <h5>Lucioledeeper</h5>

                <h6>16 heures de jeu</h6>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href=
        "http://forum.nimeria.fr/">Voir le classement général</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong here ? Sorry for the long post.

And thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a DIV with bootstrap "clearfix" class after yours pull-right and pull-left DIVs to resolve this css float problem.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fwbxbua8/

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was stuck for 3 days! Thank you again !